# Using Large number of collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am considering MongoDB to hold data of our campaign logs,

```
{
    "domain"     : ""
    "log_time"   : ""
    "email"      : ""
    "event_type" : "",
    "data" : {
        "campaign_id" : "",
        "campaign_name" : "",
        "message" : "",     
        "subscriber_id" : ""
    }
}
```

The above one is our event structure, each event is associated with one domain,

one domain can contain any number of events and there is no relation between one domain to another domain

most of our queries are specific to one domain at a time

for quick query responses I'm planning to create one collection per one domain so that I can query on particular domain collection data instead of query on whole data which contains all domains data

we will have at least 100k+ domains in the future, so I need to create 100k+ collections.
We are expecting 1 million + documents per collection.

**our main intention is index on only required collections, we don't want to index on whole data, that is why we are planning to have one collection per one domain**

which approach is better for my case

1.Storing all domains events in one collection
   (or)

2.Each domain events in separate collection

I have seen some questions on max number of collections that mongodb can support but I didn't get clarity on this topic , as far I know we can extend default limit size 24k, but if I create 100k+ collections what about performance will it get affect

Is this solution (using max number of collections) right approach for my case
Please suggest about my approach, thanks in advance

Comment: There is a limit to the number of collections you can have in 1 DB... You can [read more here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) about mongoDB limits and thresholds... I do believe that 100K collections is too much. With the correct indexes, you should be able to still get the performance your are looking for with all events in one collection.

Comment: How many documents do you expect to store in each collection on average?

Comment: we are expecting 1 million + documents per collection

Comment: The # of collections allowed per database is dependent on the size of the names space file (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Number-of-Collections-in-a-Database)

Answer (score 1):

Without some hard numbers, this question would be probably just opinion based. 
However, if you do some calculations with the numbers you provided, you will get to a solution.

So your total document count is:

```
100 K collections x 1M documents = 100 G (100.000.000.000) documents.
```

From your document structure, I'm going to do a rough estimate and say that the average size for each document will be 240 bytes (it may be even higher).

Multiplying those two numbers you get ~21.82 TB of data. You *can't* store this amount of data just one one server, so you will have to split your data across multiple servers.

With this amount of data, your problem isn't anymore one collection vs multiple collections, but rather, how do I store all of this data in MongoDB on multiple servers, so I can efficiently do my queries.

If you have 100K collections, you can probably do some manual work and store e.g. 10 K collections per MongoDB server. But there's a better way.

You can use [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) and let the MongoDB do the hard work of splitting your data across servers. With sharding, you will have one collection for all domains and then shard that collection across multiple servers.

I would strongly recommend you to read all documentation regarding sharding, before trying to deploy a system of this size.

Comment: Hey Christian, I'm very new to mongodb , Here I'm creating collection for each domain and my main intention is to have indexes for only required collections. I don't want to index on whole all domains data.

Comment: Um.. sharding and indexes are two different things. If you're new to MongoDB, I would strongly suggest to check MongoDB documentation and to read some books about it before you start designing large systems. You can even get some free dev/dba courses on their site https://university.mongodb.com/

Comment: Hey I know sharding and indexing are different concepts. Here my question is one collection with all data or separate collection for each domain which one is better.

Comment: @ramesh Like I said in my answer, if you plan to store 20 terabytes of data you **can't** do it on 1 server. So it doesn't really matter if you plan to split your documents in 100K collections or if you put them all in 1 collection on that server. See my edit for some further explanation.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Lets assume I have only 500gb of data that I can store on one server, in this scenario what do you suggest in between large collection vs single collection with full data

Comment: IMHO, one collection is still a better approach than having 100K collections.

Comment: Im planning large collections only for quick query response.If I have separate collection for each domain so that I can index only on required collection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56688/discussion-between-ramesh-and-christian-p).